# Extraer un arreglo de una lista enlazada en C

Tags: array, c, lista

Hola buen día y gracias por su ayuda, tengo una lista enlazada y lo que deseo hacer es organizar los datos de la lista en paquetes de 12, en forma de array. Al realizar la llamada a la lista enlazada y estructurar un ciclo for, no puedo emplear la asignación de apuntador dentro del ciclo for, obligando a utilizarlo fuera de él y no recibiendo los datos de la lista.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct coder{ 
    int hamming;
    struct coder * siguiente;
    struct coder * atras;
}coder;
coder * primero = NULL;
coder * ultimo = NULL;

void insertar(int * x){
    coder *nuevo = (coder*)malloc(sizeof(coder));
    nuevo->hamming= * x;
    printf("%d",nuevo->hamming);
    if (primero == NULL)
    {
        primero = nuevo;
        primero->siguiente = NULL;
        primero->atras = NULL;
        ultimo = primero;
    }else
    {
        ultimo->siguiente = nuevo;
        nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
        nuevo->atras = ultimo;
        ultimo = nuevo;
    }
}

void DecodificaryCorregir(){
    int hammingcorregir[12];
    coder *actual = (coder*)malloc(sizeof(coder));
    actual = primero;
    if (primero!= NULL){
        while (actual!=NULL){ 
            for (int i = 0; i <12 ; i++){
                hammingcorregir[i]=actual->hamming;
                actual=primero->siguiente; //<-------- aquí se presenta una
                                                     //violacion de segmento core
            }
            //actual=actual->siguiente; 
        }
    }
    else{
        perror("La lista esa vacia");
    }   

}
```

Comment: Lo que buscas es copiar los datos de la lista en el arreglo. Ok, pero que pasaría si hay más de 12 datos? ¿O que pasaría si la lista enlazada tiene 3 datos? Pues básicamente el vector solamente tuviese 3 datos y el resto de elementos quedarían con contenido basura, a excepción que se le haya dado un valor por defecto. No logro comprender que quieres lograr con el vector de 12 elementos, la verdad que no.

Comment: El resto del programa hace que la lista tenga n*12 elementos, siempre es múltiplo de 12, de ahí que sea fijo el tamaño del arreglo, se empaquetan en 12 elementos para procesarse mediante un algoritmo sobre ese arreglo.

Comment: Es redundante pero así es el diseño, básicamente es replicar un algoritmo de corrección de errores, es por eso la redundancia, una parte del programa lo fija a 12 elementos y otra parte opera con el array, no es lo óptimo pero así es requerido

Comment: El código que inserta es correcto. Y `DecodificaryCorregir` es *casi* correcto (el `malloc` que haces es inutil). Luego pregunto: ¿ Estas 100% seguro de que siempre que llamas a esa función la lista tiene una cantidad múltiplo de 12 de elementos ?

Comment: En el ``for`` la instrucción: ```actual=primero->siguiente``` siempre quedaría en el segundo elemento de la lista porque ```primero``` nunca avanza al siguiente. Si en esa instrucción te está dando violación de acceso es porque ```primero``` está apuntando Dios sabe dónde.

Comment: @DarylMendoza Entonces lo que quieres es agregar 12 elementos de la lista en el arreglo? Para lograr eso necesitarías saber si el tamaño de la lista es múltiplo de `12`. Adicionalmente, se tendría que crear más de un arreglo, debido a que, puedes tener más de un paquete de 12 elementos en la lista.